# can two AR(1) processes be cointegrated

Tags: time-series, arima, stochastic-processes, autoregressive, cointegration

Let $Y_{t}$, for $t=1,2, \dots$ be AR(1) process.
$$
Y_{t+1} = c_{1} + \phi Y_{t} + \varepsilon_{t}
$$

Next, assume that for some $X_{t}$ we have
$$
X_{t} - \beta Y_{t} = u_{t}, 
$$
where $u_{t}$ is stationary. Therefore, we can say that $X_{t}$ and $Y_{t}$ are cointegrated.

Is it possible that $X_{t}$ is also AR(1)?

**Attempt:**

Assume that $u_{t}$ is i.i.d. Then, in this simplest case $X_{t}$ is
$$
X_{t} = \beta Y_{t} + u_{t}, 
$$
therefore, it is ARMA(1,1). Though, it is not a proof of the original statement.

Comment: To be *co-integrated* you have to first be *integrated*. It is not possible for two AR(1) processes to be cointegrated unless the coefficient is 1 in both cases. This is just the definition of cointegration.

Comment: Dear @ChrisHaug , If I understand correctly, in order to speak about co-integration of the process $Y$ to another process, Y mast be $I(d)$, with $d > 1$. Is this what you mean?

Comment: $d=1$ is fine and is the basic example. Regarding your attempt, the process is not ARMA(1,1) as expressed. For ARMA(1,1) you need lag of $X_t$ and lag of $u_t$ on the right hand side but you have neither of these. You do have $Y_t$, though, and it does not belong in an ARMA(1,1) for $X_t$. @ChrisHaug, why not post a short answer based on the comment?

Comment: Dear @RichardHardy, oh, I see. In order to have ARMA, one would need $X_{t} = \beta Y_{t} + u_{t-1}$, but in the current case we have $X_{t} = \beta Y_{t} + u_{t}$.

Comment: Not quite. You need to be able to express $X_t$ as follows: $X_t=\varphi_1 X_{t-1}+u_t+\theta_1 u_{t-1}$, maybe adding a constant $\varphi_0$ as well.

Comment: I mean: sum of AR(1) and white noise is ARMA(1,1). Isn't it? cf. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/269803/adding-a-white-noise-process-to-an-arp-process

Comment: Actually, I think my conclusion is correct: $X_{t}$ is ARMA(1,1)...

Comment: @RichardHardy I didn't make it an answer because I suspected that the OP's underlying question is really closer to "Is it possible for a linear combination of AR(1) processes to be white noise?", regardless of the fact that that isn't the same as cointegration.

Comment: @ABK, you may be right (especially based on the reference), but you have not demonstrated that you are. My comment was about that (before you provided the reference).

Comment: @ChrisHaug , not really. I was asking about the cointegration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cointegration literally means "to be integrated, together" (see the usual "common trend" interpretation). It cannot logically apply to processes which are not integrated. So if you have $|\phi| < 1$ for both AR processes, they cannot be cointegrated by definition.

More precisely, the general definition of cointegration requires $X_t$ and $Y_t$ to be integrated of order $d_1$ (the *same* order for both), and that there exist a linear combination $Y_t - \beta X_t$ which is integrated of order $d_2$, with $d_1 > d_2 \geq 0$. Explicitly, the order of integration of the linear combination $d_2$ must be *strictly* smaller than the order of integration of the individual processes $d_1$, which precludes $d_1$ from being zero.