# Variance of AR(1) plus noise and its "equivalent" ARMA(1,1)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, arima, stochastic-processes, state-space-models, equivalence

Let us consider the following state-space model
$$
z_{t} = x_{t} + v_{t}\\
x_{t} = \phi x_{t-1} + w_{t}
$$
where $
\phi< 1$, the errors $v_{t}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,V^{2})$ and $w_{t}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,W^{2})$ are independent

The stationary variance of $x_{t}$ is given be $Var(x_{t}) = \frac{W^2}{1-\phi^2}$, therefore, the stationary variance of $z_{t}$ is given by
$$
Var(z_{t}) = V^{2} + \frac{W^2}{1-\phi^2}
$$

The state space model above is equivalent to ARMA(1,1) process
$$
z_{t} = \phi z_{t-1} + \theta \varepsilon_{t-1} + \varepsilon_{t},
$$
where $\theta = - \phi \frac{V}{\sqrt{V^{2} + W^{2}}}$ and $\varepsilon_{t}\sim \mathcal{N}(0,V^{2} + W^{2})$ are i.i.d. This is actually AR(1) plus noise, which is equivalent to ARMA(1,1). The prof can be found, for example, here http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~reinert/time/notesht10short.pdf

Next, let us consider "equivalent" ARMA(1,1) model. Its stationary variance is given by
$$
Var(z_{t}) = \frac{1+2\phi\theta +\theta^{2}}{1 - \phi^{2}}(V^2 + W^2),
$$
where $\theta = - \phi \frac{V}{\sqrt{V^{2} + W^{2}}}$, see, for example, https://math.unice.fr/~frapetti/CorsoP/chapitre_23_IMEA_1.pdf

I can not see that the variance of equivalent model is equal to the state-space model.

This question is related to

[Estimation of ARMA from state-space generated data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435537/estimation-of-arma-from-state-space-generated-data)

where it was shown by simulations, that "equivalence" is not working and

[Alternative construction of ARMA(1,1) process](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212388/alternative-construction-of-arma1-1-process?noredirect=1&lq=1)

where **the equivalence** is proved.

Comment: "Any time series textbook" is not all that helpful. A concrete reference could be more helpful.

Comment: Dear @Richard Hardy, I have added the reference.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in the ARMA(1,1) model. Look at 
[Alternative construction of ARMA(1,1) process](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212388/alternative-construction-of-arma1-1-process?rq=1)
where the correct ARMA(1,1) was derived.